# Need solution to fix Cross-Site Scripting Issue - Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page

Tags: xss

On running my application in VERACODE tool, using static scan, got few medium and low level issues. One of the issue which i face is Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page (Basic XSS) (CWE ID 80). This happens in many screens in my application.

One such example in my code is as follows:

```
<table border="1" width="500">
<%  java.util.Enumeration names = request.getParameterNames();
while (names.hasMoreElements()) {
String name = (String)names.nextElement();
String[] values = request.getParameterValues(name);
%>
<tr>
<td align="left"><b><%= name %></b></td>
<td align="left">
<%      for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) { %>
<%= values[i] %>
<%      
if (i < values.length - 1) { %>
<%= ", " %>
<%          }
} %>
</td>
</tr>
<%  } %>
</table>
```

The error is thrown in the line **<%= name %>**
.
Kindly help me to fix this XSS issue.

Answer (score 0):

Either switch to using <c:out > or use StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml()

Answer (score 0):

you need to import org.owasp.esapi.ESAPI and org.owasp.esapi.Encoder.
You have to use OWASP and ESAPI for this. 
Encode name where it is getting collect

```
Encoder encoder = ESAPI.encoder
String name =encoder.encodeForHtml((String)names.nextElement());
```

This may help .